# Python: Is there a way to loop through several calculations while ignoring error outputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Suppose I have 3 calculations in the following sequence:

a = 1

b = a + 1

c = b + 1

Is there a way to write a loop that goes through all the calculations in the mixed order below, ignores the erroneous c variable, and comes back to calculate c once b is calculated?

a = 1

c = b + 1

b = a + 1

Comment: Can you show what you’ve tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very weird algorithm, but here you are :

```py
def loop_calculations():
    done = False

    while not done:
        try:
            a = 1
            c = b + 1
            done = True
        except UnboundLocalError as e:
            print('caught an error, keep going')
            b = a + 1

    print(f"(a={a}, b={b}, c={c})")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop_calculations()
```

Comment: May I blow your mind!
`print(f"(a={a}, b={b}, c={c})")` is equal to `print(f"({a=}, {b=}, {c=})")`

Answer (score 0):

You could set b to some arbitrary value which it will never get, and then only calculate c if b is not that value, meaning it has already been calculated.

e.g:

```
a = 1
b = 1000000
while b == 1000000
    if b != 1000000:
        c = b + 1
    b = a + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

using choice() from random module following @mlisthenewcool mixed with @Oggy Saud ideas:

```
from random import choice

def loop_calculations():
    
    a = 1
    b = a + 1
    c = b + 1

    # Put all your variables in a list
    list = [a, b, c]

    # Initialize the result
    result = 0

    while list != []:
        try:
            random_variable = choice(list)
        except:
            continue
        else:
            result += random_variable
            list.remove(random_variable)

    return result

print(loop_calculations())
```

Answer (score -1):

your info is not so good ..... but have you ever tried the random function. you can try it once. random will throw any number from certain range... and you can do some conditioning statement and try different order of calculations.
check documentation once. :)